# Load JavaScript classes from a directory and instantiate inside code

Tags: javascript

I am building a framework and one aspect is to automatically load JS classes defined in an directory named 'modules', instantiate them and then call their constructor function. If there is a way to pass arguments to this constructor function that would be awesome!

This technique is borrowed directly from Yii (if anyone is familiar with it). Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Just found the answer to this!

I'm using Node.js and this functionality is included: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readdir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think JS has access to functionality of listing files in a folder on the server... You could do this if you have a naming convention and an array with the file names/object names like:

```
var classes = ['User','Product'];
```

running in in a `for(i)` loop and then dynamicly add script tags

```
var myScript = document.createElement('script');
```

and adding src

```
myScript.src = 'modules/' + classes[i] + '.class.js';
```

and then

```
var myObject = eval("new " + classes[i] + "()");
```

also don't forget to `.appendChild` to head or body
Another way would be to get the directory file list via a backend program, but that would not be so great for a js framework :)